# GCC runs into Out of memory with GTK+3

Tags: linux, gcc, gtk, gdk

I'm trying to compile the big project after a libraries update, and one of them was GTK - I need to migrate project from GTK 2.x to GTK 3.x. The compiler doesn't give any syntax error or dependency error, however it stalls with this:

```
    g++  -DBOOST_ASIO_DYN_LINK -DBOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION=3 -DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK
 -DBOOST_LOG_USE_NATIVE_SYSLOG -DMOKMXRP -D__DEBUG -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS 
-Wno-missing-braces -Wextra -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wformat=2 -Wswitch-default 
-Wswitch-enum -Wcast-align -Wpointer-arith -Wstrict-overflow=5  -Wundef -Wcast-qual 
-Wshadow -Wunreachable-code -Wlogical-op -Wfloat-equal -Wstrict-aliasing=2 
-Wredundant-decls -Wwrite-strings -Winit-self -rdynamic -O2 -ggdb3 -fstrict-aliasing 
-g -I./include -I/usr/include/websocketpp -I/usr/include/re2 -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 
-I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 
-I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 
-I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/harfbuzz 
-I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/libpng12 
-I/usr/include/json-glib-1.0 -I/usr/include/libtorrent -I/usr/include/jsoncpp 
-I/usr/include/webkitgtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/libsoup-2.4 -I/usr/include/libxml2 
   -UTORRENT_NO_DEPRECATE -o CMakeFiles/temp_lib.dir/CPlayer/CWebView.cpp.o 
-c ./CPlayer/CWebView.cpp
    In file included from /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:30:0,
                     from /usr/include/boost/shared_ptr.hpp:17,
                     from /usr/include/boost/date_time/time_clock.hpp:17,
                     from /usr/include/boost/thread/thread_time.hpp:9,
                     from /usr/include/boost/thread/lock_types.hpp:18,
                     from /usr/include/boost/thread/pthread/thread_data.hpp:12,
                     from /usr/include/boost/thread/thread_only.hpp:17,
                     from /usr/include/boost/thread/thread.hpp:12,
                     from /home/constantine/Downloads/digbil_player/include/digbil/digbilplayer/CWebView.hpp:20,
                     from /home/constantine/Downloads/digbil_player/src/digbilplayer/CPlayer/CWebView.cpp:1:
    /usr/include/boost/checked_delete.hpp: In instantiation of 'void boost::checked_delete(_GdkCursor*)':
    /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/shared_count.hpp:134:38:   required from 'boost::detail::shared_count::shared_count(_GdkCursor*)'
```

which stalls there untill it hits `Out of Memory!`. Happened after I started using GTK3 headers instead of GTK2.

**EDIT 1:**

Here's the output of same command with `-v` option:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/usr/bin/g++
Target: i686-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.8 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.8 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libmudflap --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-i386/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-i386 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-i386 --with-arch-directory=i386 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-targets=all --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=i686-linux-gnu --host=i686-linux-gnu --target=i686-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-D' 'BOOST_ASIO_DYN_LINK' '-D' 'BOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION=3' '-D' 'BOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK' '-D' 'BOOST_LOG_USE_NATIVE_SYSLOG' '-D' 'MOKMXRP' '-D' '__DEBUG' '-D' '__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS' '-Wno-missing-braces' '-Wextra' '-Wno-missing-field-initializers' '-Wformat=2' '-Wswitch-default' '-Wswitch-enum' '-Wcast-align' '-Wpointer-arith' '-Wstrict-overflow=5' '-Wundef' '-Wcast-qual' '-Wshadow' '-Wlogical-op' '-Wfloat-equal' '-Wstrict-aliasing=2' '-Wredundant-decls' '-Wwrite-strings' '-Winit-self' '-rdynamic' '-O2' '-ggdb3' '-fstrict-aliasing' '-g' '-I' '/home/constantine/Downloads/digbil_player/include' '-I' '/usr/include/websocketpp' '-I' '/usr/include/re2' '-I' '/usr/include/gtk-3.0' '-I' '/usr/include/atk-1.0' '-I' '/usr/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0' '-I' '/usr/include/pango-1.0' '-I' '/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0' '-I' '/usr/include/cairo' '-I' '/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0' '-I' '/usr/include/glib-2.0' '-I' '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include' '-I' '/usr/include/harfbuzz' '-I' '/usr/include/freetype2' '-I' '/usr/include/pixman-1' '-I' '/usr/include/libpng12' '-I' '/usr/include/json-glib-1.0' '-I' '/usr/include/libtorrent' '-I' '/usr/include/jsoncpp' '-I' '/usr/include/webkitgtk-3.0' '-I' '/usr/include/libsoup-2.4' '-I' '/usr/include/libxml2' '-U' 'TORRENT_NO_DEPRECATE' '-o' 'CMakeFiles/digbilplayer_temp_lib.dir/CPlayer/CWebView.cpp.o' '-c' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i686'
 /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.8/cc1plus -quiet -v -I /home/constantine/Downloads/digbil_player/include -I /usr/include/websocketpp -I /usr/include/re2 -I /usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I /usr/include/atk-1.0 -I /usr/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 -I /usr/include/pango-1.0 -I /usr/include/gio-unix-2.0 -I /usr/include/cairo -I /usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I /usr/include/glib-2.0 -I /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I /usr/include/harfbuzz -I /usr/include/freetype2 -I /usr/include/pixman-1 -I /usr/include/libpng12 -I /usr/include/json-glib-1.0 -I /usr/include/libtorrent -I /usr/include/jsoncpp -I /usr/include/webkitgtk-3.0 -I /usr/include/libsoup-2.4 -I /usr/include/libxml2 -imultiarch i386-linux-gnu -dD -D_GNU_SOURCE -D BOOST_ASIO_DYN_LINK -D BOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION=3 -D BOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK -D BOOST_LOG_USE_NATIVE_SYSLOG -D MOKMXRP -D __DEBUG -D __STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -U TORRENT_NO_DEPRECATE /home/constantine/Downloads/digbil_player/src/digbilplayer/CPlayer/CWebView.cpp -quiet -dumpbase CWebView.cpp -mtune=generic -march=i686 -auxbase-strip CMakeFiles/digbilplayer_temp_lib.dir/CPlayer/CWebView.cpp.o -ggdb3 -g -O2 -Wno-missing-braces -Wextra -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wformat=2 -Wswitch-default -Wswitch-enum -Wcast-align -Wpointer-arith -Wstrict-overflow=5 -Wundef -Wcast-qual -Wshadow -Wlogical-op -Wfloat-equal -Wstrict-aliasing=2 -Wredundant-decls -Wwrite-strings -Winit-self -version -fstrict-aliasing -fstack-protector -Wformat -Wformat-security -o /tmp/ccbR67KG.s
GNU C++ (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) version 4.8.2 (i686-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.8.2, GMP version 5.1.3, MPFR version 3.1.2-p3, MPC version 1.0.1
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/c++/4.8"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/i386-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../i686-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /home/constantine/Downloads/digbil_player/include
 /usr/include/websocketpp
 /usr/include/re2
 /usr/include/gtk-3.0
 /usr/include/atk-1.0
 /usr/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0
 /usr/include/pango-1.0
 /usr/include/gio-unix-2.0
 /usr/include/cairo
 /usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0
 /usr/include/glib-2.0
 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include
 /usr/include/harfbuzz
 /usr/include/freetype2
 /usr/include/pixman-1
 /usr/include/libpng12
 /usr/include/json-glib-1.0
 /usr/include/libtorrent
 /usr/include/jsoncpp
 /usr/include/webkitgtk-3.0
 /usr/include/libsoup-2.4
 /usr/include/libxml2
 /usr/include/c++/4.8
 /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/c++/4.8
 /usr/include/c++/4.8/backward
 /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.8/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.8/include-fixed
 /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C++ (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) version 4.8.2 (i686-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.8.2, GMP version 5.1.3, MPFR version 3.1.2-p3, MPC version 1.0.1
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: b76bde06a7376488e4b30f7e8789f5ce
/home/constantine/Downloads/digbil_player/src/digbilplayer/CPlayer/CWebView.cpp: In static member function 'static const OpaqueJSValue* CWebView::OnCampaignEnded(JSContextRef, JSObjectRef, JSObjectRef, size_t, const OpaqueJSValue* const*, const OpaqueJSValue**)':
/home/constantine/Downloads/digbil_player/src/digbilplayer/CPlayer/CWebView.cpp:791:13: warning: converting 'false' to pointer type 'JSValueRef {aka const OpaqueJSValue*}' [-Wconversion-null]
      return false;
             ^
In file included from /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:30:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/shared_ptr.hpp:17,
                 from /usr/include/boost/date_time/time_clock.hpp:17,
                 from /usr/include/boost/thread/thread_time.hpp:9,
                 from /usr/include/boost/thread/lock_types.hpp:18,
                 from /usr/include/boost/thread/pthread/thread_data.hpp:12,
                 from /usr/include/boost/thread/thread_only.hpp:17,
                 from /usr/include/boost/thread/thread.hpp:12,
                 from /home/constantine/Downloads/digbil_player/include/digbil/digbilplayer/CWebView.hpp:20,
                 from /home/constantine/Downloads/digbil_player/src/digbilplayer/CPlayer/CWebView.cpp:1:
/usr/include/boost/checked_delete.hpp: In instantiation of 'void boost::checked_delete(_GdkCursor*)':
/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/shared_count.hpp:134:38:   required from 'boost::detail::shared_count::shared_count(_GdkCursor*)'
```

**EDIT 2**

`clang` output:

```
In file included from /home/constantine/Downloads/digbil_player/src/digbilplayer/CPlayer/CWebView.cpp:1:
In file included from /home/constantine/Downloads/digbil_player/include/digbil/digbilplayer/CWebView.hpp:20:
In file included from /usr/include/boost/thread/thread.hpp:12:
In file included from /usr/include/boost/thread/thread_only.hpp:17:
In file included from /usr/include/boost/thread/pthread/thread_data.hpp:12:
In file included from /usr/include/boost/thread/lock_types.hpp:18:
In file included from /usr/include/boost/thread/thread_time.hpp:9:
In file included from /usr/include/boost/date_time/time_clock.hpp:17:
In file included from /usr/include/boost/shared_ptr.hpp:17:
In file included from /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:30:
/usr/include/boost/checked_delete.hpp:32:41: error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to an incomplete type '_GdkCursor'
    typedef char type_must_be_complete[ sizeof(T)? 1: -1 ];
                                        ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/shared_count.hpp:134:20: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::checked_delete<_GdkCursor>' requested here
            boost::checked_delete( p );
                   ^
/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:276:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::detail::shared_count::shared_count<_GdkCursor>' requested here
    boost::detail::shared_count( p ).swap( pn );
    ^
/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:354:24: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::detail::sp_pointer_construct<_GdkCursor, _GdkCursor>' requested here
        boost::detail::sp_pointer_construct( this, p, pn );
                       ^
/home/constantine/Downloads/digbil_player/src/digbilplayer/CPlayer/CWebView.cpp:161:23: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::shared_ptr<_GdkCursor>::shared_ptr<_GdkCursor>' requested here
    mpDefaultCursor = GdkCursor_Ptr( gdk_cursor_new(GDK_BLANK_CURSOR) );
                      ^
/usr/include/gtk-3.0/gdk/gdktypes.h:118:16: note: forward declaration of '_GdkCursor'
typedef struct _GdkCursor GdkCursor;
```

**EDIT 3**

Includes:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <gtk/gtk.h>
//#include <gdk/gdkkeysyms.h>
#include <gdk/gdk.h>
#include <webkit/webkit.h>
#include <webkit/webkitwebinspector.h>
#include <JavaScriptCore/JavaScript.h>
#include <JavaScriptCore/JSValueRef.h>
#include <JavaScriptCore/JSContextRef.h>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/recursive_mutex.hpp>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>
#include <cups/cups.h>
#include <cups/ppd.h>
#include <json-glib/json-glib.h>
#include <digbil/Typedefs.hpp>
#include <digbil/digbilplayer/CViewBase.hpp>
#include <digbil/digbilplayer/CBasicDB.hpp>
#include <digbil/digbilplayer/CViewUtil.hpp>
#include <digbil/digbilplayer/CWsPlatformUtil.hpp>
#include <digbil/digbilplayer/PlayerOption.hpp>
#include <digbil/digbilplayer/CUtil.hpp>
#include <digbil/digbilplayer/ILayout.hpp>
```

Code related to Gdk:

```
void CWebView::InitWindows(CViewBase::WndStyle style)
{
    CSingletonFab::GetLog().Debug(__func__, CLog::sJustSteppedIn, sClsName);

    //Set up windows.
    mpPlayerWnd = WebViewWrapper_Ptr(new CWebView::WebViewWrapper );

    gtk_window_set_keep_above(GTK_WINDOW(mpPlayerWnd->mpOuterWnd.get()), TRUE);
    /// count how many screen and monitor and move this window to 2nd screen by them
    int intXpos = 0, intYpos = 0;
    if (mMonitorNum == 2) {
        GdkScreen* pScreen = gtk_window_get_screen(GTK_WINDOW(mpPlayerWnd->mpOuterWnd.get()));
        /// if mOptionArgs.mMonitorNum higher than 2, we need use intMonitorNum.
//        size_t intMonitorNum = gdk_screen_get_n_monitors(pScreen);
        GdkRectangle dest;
        try {
            gdk_screen_get_monitor_geometry(pScreen,(gint)1,&dest);
            intXpos = dest.x;
            intYpos = dest.y;
        } catch (...) {
            CSingletonFab::GetLog().Error(__func__, "An exception is thrown",
                                        __LINE__, __FILE__, sClsName);
            intXpos = 1920;
            intYpos = 0;
        }
    }

    CSingletonFab::GetLog().Debug(__func__, "intXpos: " + boost::lexical_cast<string>(intXpos) +
                               "intYpos: " + boost::lexical_cast<string>(intYpos),
                               sClsName);
    gtk_window_move(GTK_WINDOW(mpPlayerWnd->mpOuterWnd.get()),intXpos,intYpos);

    if (style == FULLSCREEN)
    {
        gtk_window_fullscreen(GTK_WINDOW(mpPlayerWnd->mpOuterWnd.get()) );
        gtk_window_set_decorated(GTK_WINDOW(mpPlayerWnd->mpOuterWnd.get()), FALSE);
    } else if (style == WND) {
        gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(mpPlayerWnd->mpOuterWnd.get()),
                800,
                600);
    } else if (style == ALLSCREEN) {
        gtk_widget_set_size_request(mpPlayerWnd->mpOuterWnd.get(),
                                     mMonitorWidthSize, mMonitorHeightSize);
        gtk_window_set_decorated(GTK_WINDOW(mpPlayerWnd->mpOuterWnd.get()), FALSE);
    }

    //Init default cursor.
    mpDefaultCursor = GdkCursor_Ptr( gdk_cursor_new(GDK_BLANK_CURSOR) );
    g_timeout_add_seconds(FULLSCREEN_CURSOR_TIMEOUT, (GSourceFunc)HideCursor,
            NULL);

    // disable listen mouse motion event, control by unclutter
//  mMotionEventCallBackID = g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(mpPlayerWnd->mpOuterWnd),
//                                                      "motion-notify-event",
//                                                      G_CALLBACK(OnMotionEventCallBack),NULL);

    // Causes widget to have the keyboard focus for the GtkWindow it's inside
    gtk_widget_grab_focus(GTK_WIDGET(mpPlayerWnd->mpOuterWnd.get()) );
    // GTK_POLICY_NEVER: scrollbar is never presented
    gtk_scrolled_window_set_policy(
            GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW (mpPlayerWnd->mpScrollerWnd.get()), GTK_POLICY_NEVER,
            GTK_POLICY_NEVER);
    // GTK_WIN_POS_MOUSE: Windows should be placed at the current mouse position.
    // disable this setting, change to gtk_window_move() to setup the window position.
//    gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW (mpPlayerWnd->mpOuterWnd.get()),
//            GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER_ALWAYS); //GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER_ALWAYS or GTK_WIN_POS_MOUSE
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (mpPlayerWnd->mpScrollerWnd.get()),
            GTK_WIDGET(mpWebView.get()) );

    // GDK_KEY_PRESS_MASK: receive key press events
    gtk_widget_set_events(GTK_WIDGET(mpPlayerWnd->mpOuterWnd.get()),
            GDK_KEY_PRESS_MASK);
    // GDK_KEY_RELEASE_MASK: receive key release events
    gtk_widget_set_events(GTK_WIDGET(mpPlayerWnd->mpOuterWnd.get()),
            GDK_KEY_RELEASE_MASK);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (mpPlayerWnd->mpOuterWnd.get()),
            mpPlayerWnd->mpScrollerWnd.get());

    BOOST_ASSERT_MSG( mpWebView != 0, "mpWebView SHOULD != 0" );
    BOOST_ASSERT_MSG( mpPlayerWnd->mpOuterWnd != 0, "mpPlayerWnd->mpOuterWnd SHOULD != 0" );
    BOOST_ASSERT_MSG( mpPlayerWnd->mpScrollerWnd != 0, "mpPlayerWnd->mpScrollerWnd SHOULD != 0" );

    g_signal_connect(mpPlayerWnd->mpOuterWnd.get(), "delete-event",
            G_CALLBACK(OnWebviewDestroy), NULL);
    //g_signal_connect(mpPlayerWnd->mpOuterWnd,"expose-event",G_CALLBACK(OnExposeEventDummy),NULL);
    //g_signal_connect(mpPlayerWnd->mpScrollerWnd,"expose-event",G_CALLBACK(OnExposeEventDummy),NULL);
    gtk_window_move(GTK_WINDOW(mpPlayerWnd->mpOuterWnd.get()),intXpos,intYpos);

    CSingletonFab::GetLog().Debug(__func__, CLog::sSuccess, sClsName);
}
```

Comment: Need more info. Make the compiler be more chatty.

Comment: That yields nothing that could help diagnose it.

Comment: Then what else can I post?

Comment: I personally would compile with clang and see if that throws anything different, but if your codebase is really large (and probably some gcc specific foo) this is probably not feasable.

Comment: Can you show your includes? CWebView is obviously using the GdkCursor typedef without having included proper <gtk/gtk.h> or something related. Not sure if I can help you any further here without the source code, you might bring this issue up on the gtk/gnome app devel mailing list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[SOLVED]:**

Apparently it's inconsistency was because of `boost::shared_ptr` so after changing the declaration from `boost::shared_ptr<GdkCursor>` to `GdkCursor*` everything works just fine.